# Rails to always save a changed state what method would you override

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, onchange, monkeypatching

Ok.. so I have boss that's a bit of a nut when it comes to using the date as an indicator of change. He doesn't trust it.

What I want to do is have something work the same way as the date update that comes native with active record, but instead base it on an ever increasing number.. 
I know...  the number of seconds since 1973 is constantly getting bigger  Well unless you count daylight savings and things.

I'm wondering if there are any thoughts, on how to do this gracefully.. 
Note I have 20 tables that need this and I am a big fan of DRY.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html, I think this is exactly what you want.

Optimistic locking within ActiveRecord means that if a lock_version column is present on a specific table then it will be updated (+1) every time you change that record (via ActiveRecord, of course).

Comment: Nope.. it's sort of right.. But that is for locking, and editing.. I'd suspect it uses the date edited as a flag, and when you attempt to save, it check if the date on the record is the same as when you loaded the record.   Smart, and I will keep in mind for other issues... THANKS..

Comment: If there is a lock_version column present within the database table, then Rails updates that column with +1 for every change made to a row.   It doesn't have anything to do with updated_at, afaik.

Comment: I could use the lock_version and another field, last_exported_lock_version to help me find new records.. Sweet answer, and if I'd not already implemented something, I'd likely use this idea.

Comment: could you add your comment to your answer.. I want to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a mass trigger inside the database. 
The function creates a record (or updates it) in a new table called data_changed.

```
def create_trigger_function(schema)
    puts "DAVE: creating trigger function for tenant|schema #{schema.to_s}"
    sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION \""+schema+"\".insert_into_delta_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS 'BEGIN
            UPDATE \""+schema+"\".data_changes SET status = 1, created_at = now() where table_name = TG_TABLE_NAME and record_id = NEW.id;
            INSERT INTO \""+schema+"\".data_changes (status, table_name, market_id, record_id, created_at)
                                                 ( select m.* from \""+schema+"\".data_changes as ds right outer join
                                                    (select  1, CAST (TG_TABLE_NAME AS text ) as name , markets.id, NEW.id as record_id, now() from \""+schema+"\".markets) as m
                                                    on
                                                    ds.record_id = m.record_id
                                                    and ds.market_id = m.id
                                                    and table_name = name
                                                    where ds.id is null );                
            RETURN NULL;
            END;' LANGUAGE plpgsql;"    
    connection.execute(sql);
  end
```

Now all I have to do to find all the changed "products" is

```
update data_changes set status = 2 where status = 1 and table_name = 'products'
select * from products where id in (select record_id from data_changes where status = 2 and table_name = 'products')
update data_changes set status = 3 where status = 2 and table_name = 'products'
```

If a product gets updated after I do my first update, but before I do the select, then it won't show up in my select, because it's id will be reset to 1. 

If a product gets updated after I do my select, but before I do the last update,then again it will not be affected, by the last update.

The contents of my select, will be out of date, but there's no real way of avoiding that.

Comment: Oh.. I have to track the export for many different "markets", so I couldn't take the lock_version approach, but it was cool.